# fetching all the Restaurants, supermarkets, malls etc. nearby using the Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm new in iPhone Development. I'm creating an application in which i need to fetch all the  Restaurents, supermarkets, malls etc. in the nearby location using GoogleApi. Im using following link to find the venue:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=grocery_or_supermarket&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI

But I'm getting the following message:

"html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"

Please help.
Any solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Access denied" is coming because the key(AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI) you are using is not valid.
You have to register your project on on Google and have to generate unique key from this [link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
replace the generated key with the key in your link, then this will work fine.

If you have any other query let me know.

Comment: I have already registered my application and using the registered api key but it is giving the error "REQUEST_DENIED". I have also check for sponser value. Thanks

Comment: I have check your link by replacing your key with my API key and run in web browser and it works perfectly fine for me. First check that your link is working in web browser after that integrate it web browser.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide credit card information for the verification of Google Places API?. Thanks for your reply

Comment: No, you did not required credit card information for using Google Place API up to a certain limit. Did you able to integrate Google places API successfully?

Comment: I have registered the app.I have integrated the Google API as per the Google API documents,but my link is not working in web browser.Can you please suggest me some solution for this.                  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=19.1888888889,72.9083333333&radius=500&types=food&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBFtkdHvfp51Yv4JXtCB2juoNFKwSdVAd8. This is my link after integrating API key.

Comment: Its the problem of API key, delete the project from your Google project and again make a new project, do not forgot to enable Google Places API from the available API services, because by default Google place API are disabled.

Comment: why didn't you tick the answer correct if its helpful for you.